# How to clear cells that evaluate to false in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell

I tried searching for this, but I kept coming across questions of how to make a cell show as blank instead of false. I want to clear the formula out.

I am working from an access database (that i can't do much to), that contains data on sessions on our computers. What the database will give me currently is basically "Section 1, 9-10", "Section 1, 10-11", etc. There are a total of 5 sections like this for 11 hours. In the past, I've had to copy from those queries into excel sheets. What I've gotten to at this point is I can create a query for each section that just gives me the information I need, start time and duration, which I can paste into a workbook I made.

What this workbook does is take the data from those columns and moves it to page 2 sorted by hour with if statements. the problem with that is I need those if statements to go all the way across, and far enough down to be sure to include the highest number of sessions we've had, plus a comfortable buffer, so it's 7000 rows down.

After that sorting is done, I can take all the data from that second sheet and paste it into monthly records. the problem is, with there being formulas in each of those cells, it adds approximately 7-10 Mb to the file size.

Is there someway so that cells that evaluate to false have their formula removed? Or, probably more likely, a better way to go about this without much additional software?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to use an `if` formula and if it evaluates to `False` then display nothing. You can do this by setting the value for the false result to "".

`=if(expression,value if true, "")`

The alternative is to use a macro to loop through each cell and clear it if the value is false.

```
Sub falseToClear()

' Change to the range you need to parse
Set Rng = Sheets(1).UsedRange

For Each cell In Rng
    If cell.Value = False Then cell.ClearContents
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: The second one looks like what I'm after. I'll have to putz around with that later. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JPowers No problem. If my answer has solved your issue I'd love it if you could mark it as an answer. :)